# Does a proof assistant have to be interactive?

Tags: foundations

I have thought of systems like Coq & Isabelle as programming languages specialised for writing proofs.
A programming language might or might not have a REPL making it interactive but the REPL is not core to its being.

There are two questions here:

- [What makes a proof assistant a proof assistant?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/261/what-makes-a-proof-assistant-a-proof-assistant)
- [What is a Proof Assistant?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-is-a-proof-assistant)

From my reading of them `What is a Proof Assistant?` does not imply interactivity or specifically an ITP (interactive theorem prover).

`What is a Proof Assistant?` has three good quality answers that do not emphasize interactivity.

But the answers to `what-makes-a-proof-assistant-a-proof-assistant` imply it quite strongly.

The wikipedia definition of [Proof_assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant) strongly implies the term is synonymous with ITP

> "a proof assistant or interactive theorem prover"

1. Is a proof assistant the same thing as interactive theorem prover?

If not,

2. what is the difference?
3. Does it have to be interactive?

The context of this question is [what is needed to move from design by contract to using a more advanced prover?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2225/what-is-needed-to-move-from-design-by-contract-to-using-a-proof-assistant)
(I originally wrote "proof assistant" rather than "prover")
where I am thinking about proving things but not thinking about interactivity. That question might in fact be completely off topic.

---

Whether `proof assistant` means something that is intended to be *interactive* or something that can run *unsupervised* is relevant to both to whether I asked the question I intended (no - an interactive compiler would be unusual) and whether the correct question is on topic (yes - based on [Are questions about automated theorem provers on topic?](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/q/219/2432)).
It also refines the definition of proof assistant from the other two questions which I why I asked here rather than in meta.

Comment: I feel like this is somewhat getting into the “what is a sandwich” type of argument.  As we develop newer systems, we are constantly pushing the limits and can quickly get into gray areas.  But as a matter of terminology, I personally usually use “proof assistant” and “interactive theorem prover” synonymously.

Comment: So, would Automath, Metamath, and Mizar be considered proof assistants or not? They're not interactive, they're batch. I don't think it matters that much, to be frank.

Comment: Does it really matter if it is called a proof assistant? If you would like to discuss whether something is on topic on this site, you can use the meta stackexchange.

Comment: It depends what you mean by interactive. In any programming language you have to interact with the typechecker to produce a valid program, ie. if the typechecker complains and this causes you to edit your code, is this interactive? Proof assistants are no different.

Comment: Sounds to me like the answer is a clear but opinionated no then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by “interactive” to some extent, but the Mizar system is a command-line tool that checks proof scripts. It's definitely a proof assistant, and interacting with it consists of interactions that look rather like getting code to compile with an Ahead-of-Time compiler.

Does that sound like interactivity to you? It's certainly not a REPL. Nor indeed does Isabelle offer a REPL in any usual sense: interactions with it are typically via the Isabelle/jedit tool which is an IDE.

Comment: I've already decided based on other comments that the answer is no. I'm just waiting for the right expression of that.
For the purposes of this question I count an AOT compiler as non-interactive. A REPL or an IDE is interactive by design.

Comment: Actually I'll accept this for now.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the sentiment that this is to some extent a "what is a sandwich?" question but here's how we define terms on [the metamath home page](https://us.metamath.org/index.html) (I thought about editing to make it less metamath specific but that seems a bit elusive, not just as a matter of terminology but even in terms of whether the operation of these systems is sufficiently similar to use common words all the time):

- **Proof assistants** help you interactively create proofs.
- **Verifiers** verify that a database is correct - in particular, that the proofs in a database are correct. There are over a dozen verifiers available. Metamath verifiers do not make logical inferences; they just verify that the proof as stated is correct.
- **Support and other tools** perform other Metamath-related tasks. Some of these tools are also proof assistants and/or verifiers. For example, the original metamath-exe tool is a proof assistant, a verifier, and also provides various support functions such as generating HTML pages. Metamath-knife is a fast verifier in Rust that also has other capabilities. For more information, see the list of other tools for Metamath.