# Do you need a Hilbert style Epsilon operator for definitions in set theory?

Tags: foundations, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I've started to [play](https://gist.github.com/mstewartgallus/563a47cd5b6751fb2027e2e47e3bd4fa) with mechanizing some set theory stuff. I'm not sure if I want a constructive flavor or not yet.

Anyhow you can do stuff like axiomize the empty set

$$ \top \vdash \exists P. \forall x. x \notin P$$

But you seem to need something like Hilbert's epsilon for making definitions.

$$ \emptyset = \varepsilon P. \forall x,  x \notin P $$

Then you prove that the empty set really is empty $\top \vdash \forall x, x \notin \emptyset $ by applying the empty axiom and substitute existential quantification with epsilon.

I'm not sure how constructive this is and this complicates implementation concerns like capture avoiding substitution. Also to be honest I'm not really familiar with using epsilon style quantifiers.

It might help a little to add let binders but that isn't really the same issue. I don't really want to prove $\top \vdash \textbf{let} \, \emptyset = \varepsilon P. \forall x,  x \notin P \, \textbf{in} \, \forall x, x \notin \emptyset $

I'm not sure why but you don't really seem to run into the same sort of problem with type theory.

It's kind of weird because you can hand-wave the issue with axiomatic set theory by saying that whenever we mention the empty set in a theorem $\top \vdash P$ we really mean $\top \vdash \exists \emptyset, (\forall x, x \notin \emptyset) \wedge P(\emptyset)$.

Comment: In first order logic you never make definitions. And you can mechanically translate that away. On the other hand, you can always just add a constant symbol in your language, and postulate the definition as an axiom (once you proved its existence). This is what metamath does.

Comment: Hilbert's epsilon implies the axiom of choice. You can weaken the precondition to "It exists *unique* ...", resulting in the inverted iota operator (or whatever name that is).

Comment: @Trebor I would be interested in more details on the concrete approach MetaMath does. I guess you could index by axioms used but it does also seem to require theorems live in Set.

Comment: Thoughts on adding a [choice-principle] tag?

Comment: The formalisation of ZF set theory in Isabelle (Isabelle/ZF) uses definite descriptions in order to avoid assuming the axiom of choice. Details here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Formath/set-I.pdf

Comment: Apparently free logic has application to better behaving description operators https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/#defdes

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The type theories implemented in proof assistants have *definitions* which allow introduction of new symbols.

Traditional first-order logic avoids definitions by using instead a meta-theorem stating that, whenever $\forall x_1, \ldots, x_n \,.\, \exists! y \,.\, \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y)$ is proved, and $\phi$ has only the indicated free variables, we can conservatively extend the theory with a new $n$-ary function symbol $f$ and the axiom $\forall x_1, \ldots, x_n \,.\, \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n, f(x_1, \ldots, x_n))$. An example: in set theory we have $\exists! y \,.\, \forall z \,.\, z \not\in y$, therefore we may introduce a constant $\emptyset$ such that $\forall z \,.\, z \not\in \emptyset$.

This meta-theorem of first-order logic suffices for meta-theoretic studies in textbooks, but is not a workable solution if one is going to implement first-order logic. (If you try, you will just invent a little meta-language on top of first-order logic and then use that language instead, so what purpose did first-order logic serve?)

We can do without the meta-theorem by introducing Russell's *description* operator $\iota x{:}A \,.\, \phi(x)$, read as "the unique $x : A$ such that $\phi(x)$",

$$
\frac{\vdash \exists! x \in A \,.\, \phi(x)}{\vdash (\iota x{:}A \,.\, \phi(x)) : A}
\qquad
\frac{\vdash \exists! x \in A \,.\, \phi(x)}{\vdash \phi(\iota x{:}A \,.\, \phi(x))}
$$

The $\iota$ operator is less commital than Hilbert's $\epsilon x{:}A . \phi(x)$, read as "any $x : A$ such that $\phi(x)$" because the latter implies the axiom of choice and excluded middle.

If you add meta-level definitions of symbols, then $\iota$ just might be workable. (Without $\iota$ and using only symbol definitions in ZFC you cannot define any interesting term constructors because ZFC only has one relational symbol $\in$.) Notice that $\iota$ and $\epsilon$ modify first-order logic in a fundamental way by allowing formulas inside terms.

Answer (score 5):

If you're mainly interested in set theories based on FOL, then you don't need to know concrete details of what existing systems do, but rather you only need to know and understand the precise mechanism of [**definitorial expansion**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864310/21820), which is a totally generic conservative extension of an FOL theory. For a system to be user-friendly, you would need such a mechanism to be on-the-fly, and indeed this is easy to do in any Fitch-style system such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820). You might notice that the rules under "Definitorial Expansion" in that post cover the cases for predicate/function-symbols but not for constant-symbols. This is because the **∃elim** rule already covers the latter! This is not entirely a coincidence; there are two main traditions for Fitch-style systems. One features this kind of ∃elim rule, whereas the other instead has something like ( ∃x∈S ( Q(x) ) ; ∀x∈S ( Q(x) ⇒ A ) ⊢ A ). These two traditions are briefly discussed in [this paper](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Ejeffpell/papers/pelletierNDtexts.pdf) (which calls them EI and ∃E respectively).

Given this, I disagree with the other answer that implicitly suggests that this kind of mechanism goes beyond FOL, since it is the natural and obvious thing to do in the same manner as for the ∃elim rule, when it comes to a Fitch-style system. Yes, having definitorial expansion of course comes at the cost of making the system slightly more complicated than the base system, but notice that whenever any logician says they are using ZFC they in fact mean that they are using ZFC *plus on-the-fly definitorial expansion* (or something essentially equivalent). Nobody uses plain ZFC, nor do they consider what they are using as 'beyond' FOL. In fact, many set theorists think of ZFC classes as "just formulae over ZFC with one free variable", and use them in exactly the same manner as is supported by on-the-fly definitorial expansion. (One can reify these by moving to MK set theory, but that is no longer ZFC, and set theorists who work in MK set theory also use definitorial expansion over MK...)

Comment: I thought I was rather explicit about the fact that mixing formulas inside terms goes beyond first-order logic, there's no point in beating around the bush on that matter. It doesn't matter whether that's a natural thing to do, for the point I was trying to make: many meta-theorems about FOL fly out of the window once it we extend it so that the stratification between terms and formulas is gone.

Comment: By the way, how would you accommodate the subset notation $\{x \in A \mid \phi(x)\}$ using definitional extensions? That one has always bothered me.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: My point was that logicians familiar with Fitch-style systems have always considered on-the-fly definitorial expansion for constant-symbols to be just one of the two main variants of ∃elim; they do not consider it a meta-level tool. This alone is sufficient evidence that formal FOL for these logicians is not as narrow as your post suggests. It *is true* that most modern logic texts describe definitorial expansion as meta-level facts, but it *is also true* that most of them also never give a practically usable deductive system for FOL, much less a Fitch-style system, so...

Comment: @AndrejBauer: Regarding set-builder notation, you are absolutely correct that set-builder notation used in ordinary mathematics is *not* an instance of definitorial expansion. This is also why, in the Fitch-style system I linked, I explicitly included the **type-notation** rule (which corresponds to the class-specification schema for ZFC). But in fact if we have definitorial expansion then we can actually do without set-builder notation without too much trouble, because we just need to apply definitorial expansion on the appropriate specification axiom (which is just ∃elim in my system).

Comment: We can even do without class-builder notation, by applying definitorial expansion for predicate-symbols, though if we do not use any extra syntactic sugar then it would mean that we would have to write things like "ORD(k)" instead of "k∈ORD". So in some sense definitorial expansion is all we need to work comfortably 'within' ZFC. And of course, definitorial expansion for function-symbols allows us to get Powerset and Pairing and Union as function-symbols, as well as other class-functions.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: If I've understood correctly, introducing definitions and iotas does **not** go "beyond" FOL - anyway, one could perform syntactical translations on proofs (e.g. in the case of a Fitch-style system) to eliminate them, restoring the "formula-term distinction" while keeping proofs valid. The reason that some meta-theorems no longer hold in higher-order logics is completely meta-theoretic (full vs. Henkin semantics) which is not so relevant here...

Comment: It is precisely the "syntactical translations of proofs" that I am arguing against *in practice*. Those are unworkable and lead to exponential blowup easily. It is much saner to have bona fide mechanisms at the object level (not meta level) that accommodate definitions. An unrelated comment: insisting that an entity have precisely one definition seems wrong to me.

Comment: The exponential blowup is **precisely** why definitorial expansion is used in actual practical use of ZFC, and absolutely **no** set theorist who claims to use ZFC does not use it with definitorial expansion, and yet all of these consider themselves as using ZFC over FOL and nothing more. I'm unsure why you are unwilling to accept that any FOL deductive system has rules governing syntax, and that definitorial expansion as explicated in my linked Fitch-style system is of exactly the same nature as other rules (such as ∃elim) that are indisputably part of the pure FOL rules.

Comment: And sorry but I have no idea what your "unrelated comment" is about, as it seems to have completely nothing to do with my post. Please clarify that comment if you want my opinion on it.

Comment: (The fact that the translation "can" be done does not mean one must do them immediately in practice. It is just an argument for "definitions do not go beyond FOL")

Comment: I think this is drifting off topic. I'm primarily focused on the **mechanics** and **implementation** of first order logic here. Nice metatheorems aren't so important here. The fact simple renaming of variables is much easier to implement than the mess of capture avoiding substitution is much more important to me here. I feel like that is the important difference with respect to this site.

Comment: @MolossusSpondee: Have you first of all understood what I wrote in my answer? It is **solely about implementation of a humanly usable FOL deductive system** that can support ZFC in exactly the manner that set theorists use it.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrej mentioned you can define a little meta-language which compiles to first order logic.

I've been experimenting with this approach and it's simpler and better than you might expect but just not really suited to a set theory style.

You can define a little term language like

$$ e \mathrel{::=} x \mid \emptyset \mid \{ e_1 , e_2 \} \mid \bigcup e \mid \mathop{\mathcal{P}} e $$

And define an inductive predicate on variables

$$ \begin{align*}
x \mathrel{\textbf{is}}  y \iff &
  x = y \\
 x  \mathrel{\textbf{is}}  \emptyset \iff &\forall y, y \notin x \\
x  \mathrel{\textbf{is}}  \{ e , e' \} \iff &
  \forall y, y \in x \leftrightarrow (y \mathrel{\textbf{is}} e \vee y \mathrel{\textbf{is}} e')
\end{align*}$$

And so on. Basically you write a compiler.

Then you inductively prove a meta theorem that all terms are unique and exist.

$$ \vdash \exists! x. x \mathrel{\textbf{is}} e $$

However, after you gain enough power there's not really any benefit over a meta definition of terms directly as the subset of predicates that uniquely define sets.

$$  \{ P \mid [\top \vdash \exists! x. P] \} $$

Once you allow some form of definite description you lose the ability to compute decidable equality or normal forms. So you lose much of the benefit of having some sort of term language and might as well work directly with predicates equipped with proofs they uniquely define sets.

If you wanted to keep decidable equality and normal forms you would basically end up compiling some form of type theory to set theory and most versions of set theory really aren't very well suited to this.

So it's possible to define meta-languages of terms which compile to predicates and these types of DSLs could be very useful. However, any DSL which gives you the full power of set theory (some form of iota) won't be very useful over working with predicates directly.

Also you have all the usual problems of DSLs and compilers. I like parametric higher order abstract syntax for rapid prototyping of much of what I do but I can imagine it would be an extreme headache plumbing through environments explicitly with de Bruijn levels. Metatheoretically proving stuff about your DSL also seems pretty painful.