# Formalization of partial functions for combinatorial counting

Tags: coq, type-theory, formal-languages

I need assistance in defining axioms for partial functions in total function theory that is available in [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/assumptions.html).
Specifically, I'm looking for a constructive definition of a partial function that includes a constructor for obtaining a partial function from a smaller finite domain.

My use case involves formalizing the problem of counting the number of mappings from the set $\{0, 1, 2\}$ to $\{0, 1, \ldots, 4\}$. This can be represented as the size of the set of all such functions
.Additionally, I am open to including the [function extensionality axiom](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.html#functional_extensionality_dep) also thinking about using a default element in domain and range [hear](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1369/2699).

I formalized multiplication principles and solved the number of permutations problem using it.

assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please describe the class of counting problems more precisely. Are you are counting just functions from $A$ to $B$? If so, you do not need any partial functions. Instead, prove $A^{B + C} \cong A^B \times A^C$, then $A^\mathsf{unit} \cong A$, then $\mathsf{Fin}(n + 1) \cong \mathsf{Fin}(n) + \mathsf{unit}$. (You will need function extensionality.)

Comment: It might be worth drawing inspiration from (the very complete) proof of a similar fact in ssreflect: https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.finfun.html